# Windows Boost 1.64 VS2017 missing Python libraries

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-build

I am trying to build Boost 1.64 on Windows with VS2017.  Everything builds without errors, but my output libs directory is missing some `.lib`s and `.dll`s.  Specifically, the primary missing library that I need is Boost.Python.

My most recent attempt at building looks like this, although I have tried many different combinations of options:

```
.\b2 --prefix=c:\boost --build-dir=boost_build --layout=versioned toolset=msvc-14.1 address-model=64 -j4 --with-python -a --reconfigure --stage-dir=stage --build-type=complete --debug-configuration -d2 stage >build.log 2>&1
```

And my build output looks like this:

```
notice: found boost-build.jam at C:/boost_1_64_0/boost_1_64_0/boost-build.jam
notice: loading Boost.Build from C:/boost_1_64_0/boost_1_64_0/tools/build/src
notice: Searching 'C:\Windows' 'C:\Users\tsanders' 'C:\Users\tsanders' 'C:\boost_1_64_0\boost_1_64_0\tools/build/src' 'C:/boost_1_64_0/boost_1_64_0/tools/build/src/kernel' 'C:/boost_1_64_0/boost_1_64_0/tools/build/src/util' 'C:/boost_1_64_0/boost_1_64_0/tools/build/src/build' 'C:/boost_1_64_0/boost_1_64_0/tools/build/src/tools' 'C:/boost_1_64_0/boost_1_64_0/tools/build/src/contrib' 'C:/boost_1_64_0/boost_1_64_0/tools/build/src/.' for site-config configuration file 'site-config.jam'.
notice: Configuration file 'site-config.jam' not found in 'C:\Windows' 'C:\Users\tsanders' 'C:\Users\tsanders' 'C:\boost_1_64_0\boost_1_64_0\tools/build/src' 'C:/boost_1_64_0/boost_1_64_0/tools/build/src/kernel' 'C:/boost_1_64_0/boost_1_64_0/tools/build/src/util' 'C:/boost_1_64_0/boost_1_64_0/tools/build/src/build' 'C:/boost_1_64_0/boost_1_64_0/tools/build/src/tools' 'C:/boost_1_64_0/boost_1_64_0/tools/build/src/contrib' 'C:/boost_1_64_0/boost_1_64_0/tools/build/src/.'.
notice: Searching 'C:\Users\tsanders' 'C:\Users\tsanders' 'C:\boost_1_64_0\boost_1_64_0\tools/build/src' 'C:/boost_1_64_0/boost_1_64_0/tools/build/src/kernel' 'C:/boost_1_64_0/boost_1_64_0/tools/build/src/util' 'C:/boost_1_64_0/boost_1_64_0/tools/build/src/build' 'C:/boost_1_64_0/boost_1_64_0/tools/build/src/tools' 'C:/boost_1_64_0/boost_1_64_0/tools/build/src/contrib' 'C:/boost_1_64_0/boost_1_64_0/tools/build/src/.' for user-config configuration file 'user-config.jam'.
notice: Loading user-config configuration file 'user-config.jam' from 'C:/Users/tsanders'.
notice: [python-cfg] Configuring python...
notice: [python-cfg]   user-specified cmd-or-prefix: "C:\Miniconda2\python.exe"
notice: [python-cfg]   user-specified includes: "C:\Miniconda2\include"
notice: [python-cfg]   user-specified libraries: "C:\Miniconda2\libs"
notice: [python-cfg] Checking interpreter command "C:\Miniconda2\python.exe"...
notice: [python-cfg] running command 'DIR /-C /A:S "C:\Miniconda2\python.exe" 2>&1'
notice: [python-cfg] running command 'C:\Miniconda2\python.exe -c "from sys import *; print('version=%d.%d\nplatform=%s\nprefix=%s\nexec_prefix=%s\nexecutable=%s' % (version_info[0],version_info[1],platform,prefix,exec_prefix,executable))" 2>&1'
notice: [python-cfg] ...requested configuration matched!
notice: [python-cfg] Details of this Python configuration:
notice: [python-cfg]   interpreter command: "C:\Miniconda2\python.exe"
notice: [python-cfg]   include path: "C:\Miniconda2\include"
notice: [python-cfg]   library path: "C:\Miniconda2\libs"
notice: [python-cfg]   DLL search path: "C:\Miniconda2"
notice: [python-cfg] Checking for NumPy...
notice: [python-cfg] running command 'C:\Miniconda2\python.exe -c "import sys; sys.stderr = sys.stdout; import numpy; print(numpy.get_include())"'
notice: [python-cfg] NumPy enabled
notice: Searching '.' for project-config configuration file 'project-config.jam'.
notice: Loading project-config configuration file 'project-config.jam' from '.'.
notice: [msvc-cfg] msvc-14.0 detected, command: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\cl.exe'
notice: [msvc-cfg] msvc-12.0 detected, command: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\cl.exe'
notice: [msvc-cfg] msvc-11.0 detected, command: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\cl.exe'
notice: [msvc-cfg] msvc-14.1 detected, command: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\bin\HostX64\x64\cl.exe'
notice: will use 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\bin\HostX64\x64\cl.exe' for msvc, condition <toolset>msvc-14.1
'notice: [generate-setup-cmd] 14.10.25017 is 14.1'
'notice: [generate-setup-cmd] 14.10.25017 is 14.1'
'notice: [generate-setup-cmd] 14.10.25017 is 14.1'
'notice: [generate-setup-cmd] 14.10.25017 is 14.1'
notice: [msvc-cfg] condition: '<toolset>msvc-14.1/<architecture>/<address-model>', setup: 'call "C:\Users\tsanders\AppData\Local\Temp\b2_msvc_14.10.25017_vcvars32_.cmd" >nul
'
notice: [msvc-cfg] condition: '<toolset>msvc-14.1/<architecture>/<address-model>32', setup: 'call "C:\Users\tsanders\AppData\Local\Temp\b2_msvc_14.10.25017_vcvars32_.cmd" >nul
'
notice: [msvc-cfg] condition: '<toolset>msvc-14.1/<architecture>x86/<address-model>', setup: 'call "C:\Users\tsanders\AppData\Local\Temp\b2_msvc_14.10.25017_vcvars32_.cmd" >nul
'
notice: [msvc-cfg] condition: '<toolset>msvc-14.1/<architecture>x86/<address-model>32', setup: 'call "C:\Users\tsanders\AppData\Local\Temp\b2_msvc_14.10.25017_vcvars32_.cmd" >nul
'
notice: [msvc-cfg] condition: '<toolset>msvc-14.1/<architecture>/<address-model>64', setup: 'call "C:\Users\tsanders\AppData\Local\Temp\b2_msvc_14.10.25017_vcvarsx86_amd64_.cmd" >nul
'
notice: [msvc-cfg] condition: '<toolset>msvc-14.1/<architecture>x86/<address-model>64', setup: 'call "C:\Users\tsanders\AppData\Local\Temp\b2_msvc_14.10.25017_vcvarsx86_amd64_.cmd" >nul
'
notice: [msvc-cfg] condition: '<toolset>msvc-14.1/<architecture>ia64/<address-model>', setup: 'call "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Auxiliary/Build/vcvarsall.bat"  >nul
'
notice: [msvc-cfg] condition: '<toolset>msvc-14.1/<architecture>ia64/<address-model>64', setup: 'call "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Auxiliary/Build/vcvarsall.bat"  >nul
'
notice: [msvc-cfg] condition: '<toolset>msvc-14.1/<architecture>arm/<address-model>', setup: 'call "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Auxiliary/Build/vcvarsall.bat"  >nul
'
notice: [msvc-cfg] condition: '<toolset>msvc-14.1/<architecture>arm/<address-model>32', setup: 'call "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Auxiliary/Build/vcvarsall.bat"  >nul
'
notice: [zlib] Using pre-installed library
notice: [zlib] Condition
notice: [bzip2] Using pre-installed library
notice: [bzip2] Condition
Performing configuration checks

    - 32-bit                   : yes
    - arm                      : no
    - mips1                    : no
    - power                    : no
    - sparc                    : no
    - x86                      : yes
    - symlinks supported       : yes

Component configuration:

    - atomic                   : not building
    - chrono                   : not building
    - container                : not building
    - context                  : not building
    - coroutine                : not building
    - coroutine2               : not building
    - date_time                : not building
    - exception                : not building
    - fiber                    : not building
    - filesystem               : not building
    - graph                    : not building
    - graph_parallel           : not building
    - iostreams                : not building
    - locale                   : not building
    - log                      : not building
    - math                     : not building
    - metaparse                : not building
    - mpi                      : not building
    - program_options          : not building
    - python                   : building
    - random                   : not building
    - regex                    : not building
    - serialization            : not building
    - signals                  : not building
    - system                   : not building
    - test                     : not building
    - thread                   : not building
    - timer                    : not building
    - type_erasure             : not building
    - wave                     : not building

...found 1 target...
```

Things to note:

- I use Miniconda instead of a traditional Python install.  Could be an issue, although the output from `--debug-configuration` definitely seems to indicate that it is finding everything correctly.
- After adding some debug messages, I found that the `1 target` that it finds is the `all` target; I don't see any kind of build output for the boost.python sources like I see if I build additional libraries.
- Adding extra debug output hasn't been particularly helpful; even with maximum debug output I have not been able to find any errors or warnings related to Python.
- I have also tried to start from the [boost.python quickstart](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/python/doc/html/building/no_install_quickstart.html), which compiles successfully but fails to link because it cannot find `boost_python.dll`.  (Although technically I think it should be looking for something like `boost_python-vc141-mt-1_64.dll`...)

I have tried a number of combinations of options for `bootstrap.bat` (e.g. `--with-libraries=python`, `--with-python=C:\Miniconda2\python.exe`, `--with-python-root=C:\Miniconda2`) and `b2.exe`, but nothing seems to make a difference.

If I download precompiled `boost_python` libraries and put them alongside the rest of the libraries that I have built, my project builds and runs as expected. 
 Building the python libraries myself is the only thing that I am still stuck on.

I know I'm not alone; I posted this question in a [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/66cfhv/boost_v1640/), and another user mentioned that he had the same issue; unfortunately his solution was to "eventually hit on the right set of options for both bootstrap and b2".

Has anyone else run into an issue like this?

Comment: The fix mentioned in this thread looks like it is working for me: https://github.com/boostorg/build/issues/194

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up tracing this back to my `user-config.jam`, where my Python version was unspecified.

Originally, I had this configuration:

```
using python 
    : # version
    : C:\\Miniconda2\\python.exe
    : C:\\Miniconda2\\include
    : C:\\Miniconda2\\libs
    ;
```

The [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/python/doc/html/building/configuring_boost_build.html) seems to indicate that leaving "version" empty is fine; I think an empty version is supposed to mean either "default version" or "all versions".  However, this caused boost to silently skip building the python libraries.

Everything is building as expected when explicitly specifying the Python version:

```
using python 
    : 2.7                        # version
    : C:\\Miniconda2\\python.exe # interpreter
    : C:\\Miniconda2\\include    # include dir
    : C:\\Miniconda2\\libs       # library dir
    ;
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem. Just a note that in the version of boost i had - I installed it before Python which meant that none of this was listed in the user-config.jam file, just a commented example. I had to add the entire section above to get mine to work. (also, the semi-colon on the end is very important - fails silently without it)

Comment: I had this issue while cross-compiling boost 1.64 for arm-linux and this solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Building python boost 1.64 libs with Visual Studio seems to be [broken](https://github.com/boostorg/build/issues/194).

Replace `<boost_root>/‪libs/python/build/Jamfile` by [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/boostorg/python/bd7b8ecba5c211c3361c4a9af82a7a527bed384e/build/Jamfile).

I am building it [this way](https://bitbucket.org/Vertexwahn/percdems/src/0fbae71f51beb2842a2bdeccce7dbe2bf46d3f42/Build_boost_1_64_0_Visual%20Studio%2014%202015%20Win64.cmd?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default):

```
wget.exe https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59547297/Libraries/boost_1_64_0.zip -OC:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\boost_1_64_0.zip    
7za.exe x C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\boost_1_64_0.zip -oC:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64
xcopy /y boost_1_64_0\Jamfile C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\boost_1_64_0\libs\python\build\Jamfile
del C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\boost_1_64_0.zip
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" amd64
C:
cd C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\boost_1_64_0
call bootstrap.bat
b2 --toolset=msvc-14.0 address-model=64 --build-type=complete stage -j 8
```